# Python script doesn't handle lftp and sftp with call to utility

Tags: python, sftp, lftp

**PORTION OF PYTHONG SCRIPT:**

```
    try:
        print('Enter remote FTP user password:')
        self.sudo_call(['lftp','sftp://{}@{}'.format(username, address),'-e','"put','/home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"'],
        user='rfts',
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
        output = ex.output.decode('utf-8')
        raise Exception('Could not copy public key to remote user: '
                        '{}'.format(output))
```

**When run, it creates this in /var/log/secure**

```
Nov 25 15:07:02 owl-pc104-red sudo:      iao : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/Owl/menus ; USER=rfts ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lftp sftp://sftpuser5@192.168.11.153 -e "put /home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

**Using exactly that from the secure log works:**

```
/usr/bin/lftp sftp://sftpuser5@192.168.11.153 -e "put /home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

**However, the pythong script doesn't work. It asks for the SFTP password, but then gives the error:**

```
"Could not copy public key to remote user: File name missed. Try 'help put' for more information."
```

**Here is the sudo_call method**

```
    def sudo_call(self, call_list, *args, capture=True,
                  user=None, group=None, **kwargs):
        self.cache_sudo()
        command = ['sudo']

        # Run as the input user and group if specified.
        if user is not None:
            command.extend(['-u', user])
        if group is not None:
            command.extend(['-g', group])

        method = subprocess.check_output if capture else subprocess.check_call
        return method(command + call_list, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about what your `sudo_call` method looks like, but the problem appears to be in how you've split up the command line here:

```
self.sudo_call(['lftp','sftp://{}@{}'.format(username, address),'-e','"put','/home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"'],
  user='rfts',
  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

You've split `"put /home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"` into two arguments:

- `'"put'`
- `'/home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"'`

If you were to do the same thing on the command line, it would look like:

```
/usr/bin/lftp sftp://sftpuser5@192.168.11.153 -e '"put ' '/home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"'
```

And you would probably get the same error.  You need to pass the command to lftp as a single argument (and you need to avoid double-quoting it):

```
self.sudo_call(['lftp','sftp://{}@{}'.format(username, address),'-e','put /home/rfts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'],
  user='rfts',
  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thanks, larsks, but how would you account for the fact that after running the python, the secure log obtained exact correct command string that works if you type it on the command line?

Comment: I ran your suggestion from the cmd line and it gives a different error:    Unknown command `put '.

Comment: That wasn't a *suggestion*. That was a demonstration of why the quoting in your code was incorrect. Fix the quoting in your code and things ought to work correctly.